# How can I connect one row to tables in database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently working on a system for our school, and I'm having a signup/login/attendance system.

The problem is that I want to make a user which is in a row of my table to connect to another table. It is for him only the one who can access that table because it seems that whenever we login another user it redirects on the same webpage.

Is there a way I can fix that?

```
<?php
$mymail = $_POST["mymail"];
$mypass = $_POST["mypass"];

echo "$mymail";

//database connection to check inside table and query email and password
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "sistema";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin where mymail ='" . $mymail . "' and mypass = '" . $mypass . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// echo $sql;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    // while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //     echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["idnumber"]. "<br>";
    // }

header("Location: http://localhost/sistema/attendance/index.php"); /* Redirect browser */

} else {
header("Location: http://localhost/sistema/signup/index2.html"); /* Redirect browser */
    // echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

//THIS IS JUST THE CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE AS WELL AS THE QUERY, I separated the HTML form

Comment: You can use a `JOIN` to connect two tables together. Or are you talking about a HTML form..?

Comment: Yes sir, Im talking about the form, the problem is that the user(in a row) himself can just access a table in my database just like a person who had his own profile

Comment: You'll really need to show some code and some examples, otherwise we can't know how it works. We don't see your code unless you show it to us. :-)

Comment: okay sir just a minute

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 1):

you can store him user id in a **session**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
//after login that user
$_SESSION["id"] = $_Post['id'];
$_SESSION["id"] = $_Post['username'];
?>
```

you have to start session every page and you can use that user id anyway on your website 
 to call `$_SESSION["id"]`

if he click logout

```
unset($_SESSION["id"]); & unset($_SESSION["id"]);
```

Comment: sir? how can i add those in my codes (in the comment) Edit: Please elaborate sir, im just a beginner

Comment: sir, i used header in which it redirects to different web, how can i use that ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin where mymail ='" . $mymail . "' and mypass = '" . $mypass . "'";

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Start session
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

  if(! $conn){
      die('not conected :'.mysqli_error());
  }

#$conn =new mysqli("localhost","root","","mystudy");
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['psw'];
    $qry="SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
        $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['SESS_user_ID'] = $users['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_user'] = $users['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_user_EMAIL'] = $users['user_email'];
        session_write_close();
        header("Location: /any your path url/page.php");
        }else{
        header("Location: /any your path url/error_page.php");
        }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
//Start session
    session_start();
    $userid=$_SESSION['SESS_user_ID'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE id='$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>EMAIL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["username"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
    <?php } }?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: answer appreciated sir, but are these codes applicable on my problem? My problem is just that i want a user from a row have their own identity in which different table has. if these codes are helpful, can you please specify what part? Thank you so much

Comment: you fetch the datas form your data base table

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin where mymail ='" . $mymail . "' and mypass = '" . $mypass . "'";